# Command Line net use mapped path without Drive letter doen't appear in Windows Explorer

Tags: mappeddrive, handler-mappings

I've searched extensively and have not found a post with the answer.

If you use Explorer to "Add Network Location", it will add that mapped path under the used drive letters area on the left without a drive letter.
[Windows Explorer Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwXMU.png)

Due to having more servers to connect to than there are drive letters, I am trying to script this tedious mapping process into a batch file.

Using net use

```
net use \\servername\folder /PERSISTENT:Y
```

The path mapped successfully without using a drive letter. Good!

```
OK                     \\DC1server\Log     Microsoft Windows Network
```

But how do I now get those mapped paths without drive letter to appear in Windows Explorer as shown in my image example above?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`mklink /D C:\AA_drive \\DC1server\Log`

This will create a folder on your C drive called "AA_drive ", which contains the contents of \DC1sever\Log.

(technically "AA_drive" is a symlink, but it acts exactly like a folder)